# Edit model via ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I'd like to make the following thing in my webisite [image: editing the model via ajax]
Could anybody suggest me a way? I can't find any example.

UPDATE: Here's what I'd like to do in asp.net mvc 3 - http://encosia.com/blog/media/images/inline-text-editing.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can see an [Example using ASP.NET (not MVC)](http://encosia.com/seamless-inline-text-editing-with-aspnet-ajax/)  but you can reuse their javascript logic at least.

**EDIT:**
[Here you can see a working example in MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/MVC3-Inline-Edit-JQuery.aspx)... hope this helps!

Comment: @AlexMaslakov, Nice you already seen that article. Thought you just found an image of WHAT you want it finished :) Happy coding!